# How can I get iTunes Radio on my iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, music.app, itunes-radio

I can't find the iTunes Radio section in the music app. How can I get iTunes Radio to work?

Answer (score 1):

It should appear as a Radio icon on the lower left. If it doesn't, try closing the Music app by swiping up from the App Switcher view, then re-starting, making sure that you are connected to the Internet when you open the Music app.

Also, make sure that you are using an Apple ID that is based in the US.

Comment: I think my Apple ID is based in Canada, how can I get an ID that's based in the US?